# Why do famous people become famous?

Tags: sociology

Why do famous people become famous?

Is it because how historians pick them and then portray them or can one become famous by pursuing it?

E.g. was Alan Turing such person that he deserves, how his portrayed or is it merely by change that some historian choose to write about Alan Turing, rather than someone else around Turing?

Comment: Turing is famous for his groundbreaking work, very different from a "public scholar" who is famous for popularizing science to the general public, rather than groundbreaking contributions. Both are important, but original, groundbreaking work is quite rare, which is why you know Turing's name.

Answer (score 1):

People become famous when they fit certain loose criteria:

1. Society has to actually care about what they are doing, saying, etc. This can be in a good or bad light, but people should have an opinion either way.
2. They need exposure. You could have the greatest person ever living under a rock, and he would never become famous. This exposure sometimes happens after death though, which leads to the next point.
3. Society needs to be ready to accept what they are doing/saying. (ie Nobody believed Galileo and he was an outcast, but he is now a famous figure for being the first to prove the earth isn't the center of the universe.)
4. The person needs to be, say, or do something not ordinary. This is why not everyone is famous. Either in a good way or bad, a famous person always excels at their craft, found out something new, or had some extraordinary talent.
5. The person receives exposure from another famous person (ie famous writers/websites/celebrities mentioning them)

As far as I know, these are the main things that make someone famous in either the present or the past. Feel free to edit/add points to the list.

Comment: Don't you think it's possible also that they were selected by someone writing about them? That there might have existed e.g. many Galileos, but some historian decided to write about Galileo particularly.

Comment: @mavavilj That would still fall into the points I mentioned, mainly the exposure one though. Any writer could choose to write about any person. The difference is when a writer with a lot of exposure writes about them, giving that person an immediate boost in their own exposure. I'll add that to the list

Comment: @mavavilj Galileo was written about because his work was groundbreaking, and leads to Newton.  His fame is not unwarranted, nore merely a factor of author's choosing to write about him.  Time filters out the chaff.